# How do I override charging current on Huawei Honor 6?

Tags: root-access, charging, huawei, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

On `SonyEriccson Xperia X10i` I do this:

```
echo 1000 > /sys/devices/platform/msm_hsusb/gadget/chg_current
```

This allows faster charging from computer's USB port (if I know it can source more than 500mA) or limited/prohibited charging in case of I to economize the power of computer.

But how do I do this on `Huawei Honor 6`? It doesn't seem to have `msm_hsusb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can find charger-related data at `/sys/class/hw_power/charger/charge_data`.

Current can probably be set using `cin_limit` knob (it does not apply immediately, I need to wait for several seconds. Current is in mA and is probably rounded somehow). Charger can be turned off immediately using `echo 0 > enable_charger`.

Answer (score 5):

The path in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/93080/96277) didn't work, guess it is not the true path.

[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=63463031) is my own post at XDA forum showing a script running using a macro. The path according to what worked for me and steps involved are explained. It shows a macro based implementation allows the path which works for me.

I am thankful for the earlier post that pointed this file.

To summarize:

1. Path posted earlier lead me to the file but did not allow me to change values. Probably because this is a sysfs file and the path turned out to be 
   `/sys/devices/amba.0/fdf0a000.i2c/i2c-0/0-006b`.
2. For some reason I could not echo 0 to the file to change it. Only option I could think of was to copy the file when it's not charging into a separate 
   folder in SD card and paste this into the system at the desired charging level to fool the system into behaving as if it was charged.
3. To do this, I mounted `sys` as rw first making SELINUX permissive and copied the file into SD card. Next was writing a script  to copy this into system.

   ```
   su –c "cp /storage/emulated/legacy/for_testing/enable_charger /sys/devices/amba.0/fdf0a000.i2c/i2c-0/0-006b"
   ```

   To run the script at appropriate charge automatically I used a macro written using MacroDroid app (far more  easy to learn compared to Tasker)

This whole exercise ran smoothly.

I would be happy if someone can:

- suggest a better way
- help with file information pertaining to note 2 , my old device and if at all possible to do

Comment: please quote importing steps and tips from the website you have linked to. The website can be moved or changed and this would render your answer useless. Thanks in advance