# How do I set battery charge min-max range to make it degrade with time less?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

As far as I know, LiIon batteries should be kept in about 40%-80% range in order to degrade more slowly.

On my laptop I use the following commands to make it change battery conditionally, only when it's lower than 45% and up to 90% instead of to 100%:

```
tpacpi-bat -v -s ST 1 45
tpacpi-bat -v -s SP 1 90
```

How do I do the same for Android? I can [control the charger](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/93080/5387) from software, so it should be definitely possible.

Device: Huawei Honor 6 (H60-L04)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it for the same device cutting off charging at am upper level.
 [How do I override charging current on Huawei Honor 6?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92413/how-do-i-override-charging-current-on-huawei-honor-6/127286#127286)
Surely something on those lines can be implemented for lower l level maybe a macro to shutdown the phone ( too drastic) or sound alarms and send text messages or mails if you are not close to the phone
Hope this helps

Comment: I'll probably write a program that periodically polls current charge level and does `echo 0 > enable_charger` automatically.

Comment: @Vi0 :-) were you able to echo 0.. I couldn't at all and had to copy paste file. Big thanks to you for pointing that file

Comment: `enable_charger` is a typical sysfs/proc knob which should  be perfectly readable by `cat` and writable by `echo ... >` (as root, obviously).

Comment: @Vi0...Thanks..which means I am trying the command with wrong syntax. I am Noob in Linux and took help to try this. May I request you to kindly help write the complete command? Thanks in advance

Comment: For example, I have the following script at host: `adb shell 'su -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/hw_power/charger/charge_data/enable_charger"'`

Comment: Thanks @Vi0.  Looks the the syntax is same as I used ...wonder why it didn't work. Anyway, got the end result but just curious if there are exceptions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30905/discussion-between-vi0-and-beeshyams).

Comment: Have you received a notification of my reply in the chat? (I'm not sure how reliably this "move to chat" feature works).

Comment: Yes. Received  and  replied on chat please