# Charging problem. Please help

Tags: charging

My phone (Note3, CustomOS: Phronesis) got a charging problem last night. It does not charge properly when running or if the screen is off now. Usually the LED went on while charging but it stays off now. Tasker is able to detect a power source (i had my Tasker icon change to a battery when connected) but the phone seems to cut off the charging current - like i assume it does it when it hits 100%, If connected now and i use it then the discharge is exactly comepensated, i. e. if i use it for 30 minutes, it stays at 78% the whole time....in fact my power bank led is flashing parallel to power consumption actions... Hardware problems can be 99,99% ruled out, since it charges normally if i shut it down completely.

Last night i had a SuperSU update (automatically) which was asking for the permission for SuperSU itself (i think, also confusing) and for the zygote process... (Expert info: shell, ps ...grep: just 1 process), which surprised me... i think i didn't grant them... (it's not in the app list- didn't ask again)

I also tested the QI - same thing: the phone detects it (effect:visual "smoke rings" on the screen) and immediately it says "wireless charging stopped" (in german)

- Did i accidently lowered the cut-off charging from 100% to a much lower number ? If so , how to revert ?
- Beside USB-Mode (MTP/PTP,Charging/etc.) and USB Fast Charging....anything else affecting USB handling ?

Hints (even for for Kernel Auditor Mod settings) are welcome.

I found something similar [How do I override charging current on Huawei Honor 6?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92413/how-do-i-override-charging-current-on-huawei-honor-6)  and i need the files for my Note3...

EDIT: a faulty version of the app 3c was the culprit...

Comment: Write an answer. How were you able to find out that the app was the problem? How did you change it? Etc.

Comment: i saw the changelog of their next version "fixed charging...." , where it was mentioned - so i was very lucky